# Scala: Create Map[String, Seq[Group]] from Array[Group]

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have a class called Group

```
class Group(id: Int, name: String, category: String) {

}
```

I am trying to convert `Array[Group]` to `Map[String, Seq[Group]]` with `category: String` as key. I want to create an empty `Seq[Group]` and add Group if the key does not exist otherwise update the `Seq[Group]`. I am not sure how to update the Seq if the key already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**groupBy** will do it all.

```
arrayOfGroups.groupBy(_.category)
```

Just the result will be a `Map[String, Array[Group]]` (because the original container was an array). Array is not exactly a Seq, so if you want one, you may do

```
arraysOfGroup.groupBy(_.category).mapValues(_.toSeq)
```

You may replace the `toSeq` by any more precise transformation. 
It would also be possible to do `arrayOfGroup.toSeq.groupBy(_.category)`